# iMessage Plugin Gone from Messages

Tags: macos, messages

So I accidentally deleted the iMessages plugin from the Messages app on El Capitan. Now the app is broken and nothing works. Anyway I could get this back?

[image: :/][image: Plugin Folder]

Comment: You deleted it & emptied trash? System reinstall then, or possibly dig it out of the installer using Pacifist.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough this usually has a simple fix to it. Yes you *may* have to reinstall MacOS but that can be done over top of what you already have with no danger of losing anything. However another approach might be in order.

Download the latest **combo** update from Apple [here](https://support.apple.com/downloads/el%2520capitan%2520latest%2520update). Run it, and reboot when done. it is likely to fix the issue.

If not then boot into recovery mode and reinstall your OS. You will then likely have to re-apply any subsequent updates again to the base system that was just reinstalled.